# Correct way to user PFQuery to query relational data like Pointer

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery

Ok so let's say I have a post of an event, and users can click a button to notify that they are attending this event. As of now I have a class called Activity in which I save the current user and the event to this class, so theres 2 columns. If I want to query all users who are attending an event, am I headed in the right direction to do this, or am I doing it complentely wrong?

So far I have:

```
-(PFQuery*)queryForTable {

PFQuery *activityQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Activity"];

[activityQuery whereKey:@"event" equalTo:self.event];
[activityQuery includeKey:@"going"];

return activityQuery;
}
```

cellForRowAtIndex:

```
 UILabel *title = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:1];
 title.text = [object objectForKey:@"going.username"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually see what you have been done in the **Parse** dashboard. That's also their purpose to develop a data browser like this. It's way more convenient.

For your case, you just need to check whether the type is **Pointer**. Try to click on that if so in the dashboard. It will direct you to the target object.

Would suggest you to read this article first, it's about the relation:
https://parse.com/docs/relations_guide
Then, you should go check the iOS SDK tutorial:
`includeKey` is definitely what you need to use.

Here is the sample from **Parse**:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Comment"];

// Retrieve the most recent ones
[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

// Only retrieve the last ten
query.limit = 10;

// Include the post data with each comment
[query includeKey:@"post"];


[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *comments, NSError *error) {
    // Comments now contains the last ten comments, and the "post" field
    // has been populated. For example:
    for (PFObject *comment in comments) {
         // This does not require a network access.
         PFObject *post = comment[@"post"];
         NSLog(@"retrieved related post: %@", post);
    }
}];
```

Comment: That's not what I was asking for, but thanks for the answer Lucas

Comment: If you play around the data browser, that's also pretty you can do in code. I t means that YES. You can do it by creating object that way.

Comment: I've updated my question to show my query, my next question is can I use dot notation to retrieve the users information?

Comment: Answer is no. You can only get a property using that syntax. Parse has a full documentation to teach you how to fetch the data using Pointer, Relation. Go with that.

Comment: So I can just use the includeKey, without dot notation, and define what properties I need in the cell?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks right on so far. Then to retrieve your Activity class values, you can use:

```
PFQuery *activityQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Activity"];
// Set contraints here, example:
[activityQuery setLimit:100];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *array, NSError *error) {
if (!error) {
// Success, do something with your objects.
}
}];
```

Comment: Ok so how do I set it up to where I can retrieve the profile image and username for the user who is attending. Im confused about using the includeKey and how far I can reach into the relation. –

Comment: Look into PFQuery. You can set up a query to get data from users.